# Finding all $n$ such that $\sigma(\sigma(n))=2n$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisor-sum

> Find all $n$ such that $\sigma(\sigma(n))=2n$.

I know how to solve it for even number. Let $n=2^kt$, where $t\neq 1$. Than $\sigma(\sigma(n))=\sigma((2^{k+1}-1)\sigma(t))\geq (2^{k+1}-1)\sigma(t) + \sigma(t)>2^{k+1}t=2n$. So, if $n$ is even, than $n=2^k$. Than $\sigma(\sigma(n))=\sigma(2^{k+1}-1)$ and it must be equals to $2^{k+1}$. So, $2^{k+1}-1$ must be a prime number.

Comment: What is $\sigma(n)$?

Comment: The sum of divisors

Comment: Your first inequality is not explained clearly. It appears you are thinking divisors of $(2^{k+1}-1)\sigma(t)$ include $(2^{k+1}-1)d$ and $d$ separately, where $d$ runs over divisors of $\sigma(t)$, but these lists can have overlaps. For example, take $k=1$ and $t=5$. Then $(2^{k+1}-1)\sigma(t) = 18$, and its divisors of the form $(2^{k+1}-1)d = 3d$ where $d$ divides 6 are 3, 6, 9, and 18, while the values of $d$ are 1, 2, 3, and 6. These lists overlap twice. Computing $\sigma$ of a number allows each divisor just once, so it appears the justification for your first inequality is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

This is a well known problem and the $n$ that solve the equation $\sigma(\sigma(n)) = 2n$ are called

> **superperfect numbers**

and have been defined by D. Suryanarayana in about 1969. Here is the sequence of solutions to your equation: [A019279](https://oeis.org/A019279)

You can find a lot of information here: ["Superperfect Number." From MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SuperperfectNumber.html)

**To your question:** All even superperfect numbers are $n = 2^{p-1}$ if $2^p-1$ is prime (Mersenne prime). Whether an odd superperfect number exists is still an open question in number theory.

If you are interested in this topic I suggest this papers:

- [Cohen, G. L. and te Riele, J. J. "Iterating the Sum-of-Divisors Function." Experim. Math. 5, 93-100, 1996.](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.52.868&rep=rep1&type=pdf)
- Suryanarayana, D. "Super Perfect Numbers." Elem. Math. 24, 16-17, 1969. (I dont have a pdf)